# Looking for onRowEdit event in jqGrid with inline editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I do have a jqGrid with inline editing (`EditActionIconsColumn = true`). I want to change the properties of edit fields when use click on edit icon in Action column of jqGrid. For this implementation, I am looking for an event which occurs after the row gets ready for user modifications.

I am not using `grid.editRow()`. I am using action column where `EditActionIconsColumn = true`.

I am trying something like

```
$("#grid1").jqGrid().on("editRow", function() {  

});
```

But not working. Did any one  tried this methodology for jqGrid?

I have used `EditActionIconsColumn` in server code like below with reference to the [demo](http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/mvc/jqgrid/) (Inline Row> Editing: Action Icons (save, delete, cancel))

```
    public void EditRowInlineActionIcons_SetUpGrid(JQGrid ordersGrid)
    {
        ordersGrid.Columns.Insert(0, new JQGridColumn
                                        {
                                            EditActionIconsColumn = true,
                                            EditActionIconsSettings = new EditActionIconsSettings
                                            { 
                                                SaveOnEnterKeyPress = (bool?) ViewData["enterData"] ?? false,
                                                ShowEditIcon = (bool?) ViewData["editData"] ?? true,
                                                ShowDeleteIcon = (bool?) ViewData["delData"] ?? true
                                            },
                                            HeaderText = "Edit Actions",
                                            Width = 50
                                        });

        ordersGrid.DataUrl = Url.Action("EditRowInlineActionIcons_DataRequested");
        ordersGrid.EditUrl = Url.Action("EditRowInlineActionIcons_EditRow");            

        // setup the dropdown values for the CustomerID editing dropdown
        EditRowInlineActionIcons_SetUpCustomerIDColumn(ordersGrid);
    }
```

Comment: You write about `EditActionIconsColumn` which is not exist in jqGrid. I suppose that you use some extension which uses jqGrid. It's important to see JavaScript which creates jqGrid. Moreover it's important to know which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: Oleg,I have gone through lot of answers from you. I am glad that you have responded to my question. We have used free jqGrid of version 4.4.1. Please look at the update in my question.

Comment: jqGrid is **pure JavaScript** library implemented as jQuery plugin. [The link](http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/mvc/jqgrid/) point to old *commercial* jqSuite product (see [the prices](http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/mvc/jqgrid/)). You current code generate JavaScript code, which you can see if you open the source of web browser. There are some way how one can specify `oneditfunc` callback of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow). We should come to JavaScript and to specific jqGrid. For example you can use `$.jgrid.inlineEdit.oneditfunc`

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Based on your response and my research it looks like custom Action buttons will solve my problem. I will modify Action column accordingly.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you in some way.